# Generating points within a Menger Sponge (fractal shape)

Tags: python, recursion, fractals

I am trying to generate a lattice of points in the shape of a Menger sponge or Sierpinski sponge.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge This link details how the shape is mathematically constructed.

I wanted to find a way where I could make this shape using recursion to remove the necessary cubes.

I looked online but I could only find code which generated 3d renderings of the shape and not a lattice of points.

It is worth mentioning that I am not familiar with OO programming which seemed to be the general method the examples I found used.

I then tried to make a 2D version to see if I could implement it, but the only version I got to work was by manually subtracting the areas needed.

This is what I've gotten to work, only removing the first square from the centre:

`

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

size = 12

x = []
y = []

for index_x in np.arange(size):
    for index_y in np.arange(size):
        x = np.append(x, index_x)
        y = np.append(y, index_y)


     

# step 1: remove central box
x_box = []
y_box = [] 
for index_1 in np.arange(144):
    
    if (x[index_1] < size/3 or x[index_1] >= 2/3 * size or 
        y[index_1] < size/3 or y[index_1] >= 2/3 * size):

        x_box = np.append(x_box, x[index_1])
        y_box = np.append(y_box, y[index_1])
        
# step 2: remove central square in each surrounding square
# Do the same steps as above but for the other smaller squares


            

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.scatter(x_box, y_box)
ax.set_title('Menger Sponge')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')

plt.show()
```

`

[image]

This is what my code produces.

Is there an easier / better way of implementing this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a *recursive* element to your code.  I would also suggest thinking in terms of 2D (and eventually 3D) matricies instead of 1D arrays and explore numpy's abilities in depth:

```
import numpy as np

def menger(matrix, size):
    quotient, remainder = divmod(size, 3)

    if remainder == 0:
        for x in np.arange(0, size, quotient):
            for y in np.arange(0, size, quotient):
                view = matrix[x:x + quotient, y:y + quotient]

                if (x // quotient) % 3 == 1 and (y // quotient) % 3 == 1:
                    view *= 0

                menger(view, quotient)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    SIZE = 27

    matrix = np.ones((SIZE, SIZE))

    menger(matrix, SIZE)

    plt.matshow(matrix)
    plt.colorbar()
    plt.show()
```

[image]